# What is self in a trait with generics?

Tags: rust, traits

The goal: implement a default implementation of a trait for any type which has a `to_string()`.

So my approach might actually be completely wrong. But I am asking the question this way first because it's an interesting one nonetheless.

```
use core::fmt::Display

trait MyStyle<T: Display> {
  fn pretty(&self) -> String {
     let buf = self.to_string();
     // manipulate buf
     buf
  }
}
```

In the above code, what exactly is `self`? My env (through `rust-analyzer`) just tells me `self: &Self // size = 8, align = 0x8`. But what type is it?

Obivously this code doesn't work, or I wouldn't be here, because I get

> the method `to_string` exists for reference `&Self`, but its trait bounds are not satisfied.

If it says `to_string` exists, that suggests that `self` could be some reference to `Display`, but I don't understand the rest, and why it does not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Self` in a trait refers to the type implementing that trait. Thus, in the trait definition it represents *any* type that implements that trait. You could think of it as a generic `S` where `S: MyTrait<T>`. It does not refer to one singular type.

> The goal: implement a default implementation of a trait for any type which has a to_string().

This is pretty simple and you may have over complicated things by making your trait generic. This is likely what you want:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

trait MyStyle: Display {
    fn pretty(&self) -> String {
        let buf = self.to_string();
        // manipulate buf
        buf
    }
}
```

Likely with an additional `impl<T> MyStyle for T where T: Display {}` to actually create a blanket implementation for anything that implements `Display`.

Comment: This is indeed how to resolve my underlying implementation problem! Thanks. I am thinking I should actually accept @vallentins 's response though, because of the way I framed my question...my bad

Comment: @transient_loop That's fine, each answer addressed your question a different way. Though I would recommend adjusting your title to better reflect the framing since vallentin's answer doesn't really address "what is self" :)

Answer (score 4):

In a trait impl, `&self` is basically syntactic sugar for `self: &Self`, and `Self` is a placeholder type for the actual type that implements that trait. This is especially apparent in traits that define constructor-like associated methods, like the [`Default` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/default/trait.Default.html), which is essentially:

```rust
trait Default {
    fn default() -> Self;
}

struct A {};
impl Default for A {
    fn default() -> A { // NOTE: Self == A here
        A {}
    }
}
```

Beware that adding trait bounds on a generic trait is quite restrictive. What's more idiomatic is to make the trait completely generic, and then define a blanket impl. For example

```rust
trait MyStyle {
     fn pretty(&self) -> String;
}

impl<T> MyStyle for T where T: Display {
    fn pretty(&self) -> String {
        let buf = format!("-~<[{}]>~-", self);
        buf
    }
}


fn main() {
    println!("{}", 123.pretty());
}
```

Prints:

```
-~<[123]>~-
```

[Live Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=851ec503e40b63cf991a28da17a8a77f)

Comment: There's a blanket implementation of [impl ToString for T where T: Display](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#impl-ToString-for-T), so it's perfectly valid to call `.to_string()`

Answer (score 2):

> the method `to_string` exists for reference `&Self`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
> the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
> `Self: std::fmt::Display`

The wording is just a bit confusing. The compiler is **not** saying that the method `to_string()` exists **for** `&Self`. It's saying that the method [`to_string()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string) exists, period. The name `to_string()` refers to an actual method.

For instance if you instead called `self.foo_bar_baz()` (which doesn't exist).

```rust
let buf = self.foo_bar_baz();
```

Then the compiler would say:

> no method named `foo_bar_baz` found for reference `&Self` in the current scope
> method not found in `&Self`

Because a method named `foo_bar_baz` doesn't exist. So it's only saying that `to_string()` exists. Not that it specifically exists for `&Self`.

---

Separately, the compiler is saying `to_string()` exists. However, the trait bounds `Self: std::fmt::Display` are not satisfied. So it is not possible to call `.to_string()` for `&Self`.

Comment: This is the actual response to my question, I guess I should accept this one....but @kmdreko 's answer is the response to my underlying implementation problem...thanks.

Comment: @transient_loop Your welcome. Accept the answer you find appropriate, it won't hurt my feelings regardless of which one you accept :)